# The method 'update' was called on null

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, dart, input

When I try to update the task values through the edit page, I get the following error

```
The method 'update' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: update(Instance of 'Tasks')
```

Form key

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formStateKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

This is one of the fields for entering text

```
                     child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty || value.trim() == "") {
                            return 'This field is required';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          _taskName = value;
                        },
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: widget.name),
                     
                      ),
```

The code that is triggered when the "edit" button is pressed.

```
                                onPressed: (() {
                                  if (_formStateKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    _formStateKey.currentState.save();

                                    dbHelper
                                       .update(Tasks(widget.id,
                                        _taskDate,
                                        _taskName,
                                        _taskRepeat,
                                        _taskPriority,
                                        _taskScore,
                                        _taskDone))
                                        .then((data) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        goToMainPage();
                                      });
                                    });
                                  }
                                }),
```

The update method by which the task is modified.

```
 Future<int> update(Tasks tasks) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update(
        'tasks',
        tasks.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?',
        whereArgs: [tasks.id],
      );
  }
```

Refreshing from the main page works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, it seems like `dbHelper` is null.

Are you initializing `dbHelper` anywhere because you haven't provided the
code where you do so.

So, to put it simply, you need to put the code below somewhere in your app.

```dart
final dbHelper = Tasks(...) // Fill your data in the 3 dots.
```